# CVXPY, least-squares Optimization, wrong constraint formulation

Tags: python, numpy, constraints, minimization, cvxpy

First of all, I'm sorry if my questions doesn't make sens, I am new using CVXPY library and I don't understand everything :/

I am trying to solve a minimization problem that I thought would be easy handle.
I got a matrix S dimensions (9,7) with known coefficients, B dimensions (1,7) with known coefficients, Alpha dimensions (1,7) what I need to find, with various constraints :

- Alpha must be positive
- The sum of all the coefficients of Alpha must be equal to 1

I need to optimize Alpha such as : **A @ Alpha-B=0.**
I discovered CVXPY and thought least square optimization was perfect for this issue.

This is the code  I wrote   :

```
Alpha = cp.Variable(7)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(S @ Alpha - B))
constraints = [0 <= Alpha, Alpha<=1, np.sum(Alpha.value)==1]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

result = prob.solve()

print(Alpha.value)
```

With

```
S= np.array([[0.03,0.02,0.072,0.051,0.058,0.0495,0.021 ],
 [0.0295, 0.025 , 0.1  ,  0.045 , 0.064 , 0.055 , 0.032 ],
 [0.02  , 0.018 , 0.16  , 0.032 , 0.054 , 0.064 , 0.025 ],
 [0.0195, 0.03  , 0.144 , 0.027 , 0.04  , 0.06  , 0.04  ],
 [0.02  , 0.0315, 0.156 , 0.0295 ,0.027 , 0.0615 ,0.05  ],
 [0.021 , 0.033 , 0.168 , 0.03  , 0.0265 ,0.063 , 0.09  ],
 [0.02  , 0.05  , 0.28  , 0.039 , 0.035 , 0.055 , 0.04  ],
 [0.021 , 0.03 ,  0.22  , 0.0305, 0.0255, 0.057 , 0.009 ],
 [0.0195, 0.008 , 0.2 ,   0.021 , 0.01 ,  0.048 , 0.0495]])

B=np.array([0.1015, 0.0888, 0.0911, 0.0901, 0.0945, 0.0909, 0.078 , 0.0913,
       0.0845])
```

My issue is the following one :

- Without the constraint **np.sum(Alpha.value)==1**, the code gives me results; but when I add the constraint it returns me

```
None
```

I presume the formulation is not good, but I have no Idea how to write it in another way?
Or maybe the problem doesn't have solution?
Thank you for your time

Comment: shouldn't `A @ Alpha-B=0` be a constraint rather than a objective goal?

Comment: try `np.sum(Alpha)==1` or `Alpha.sum()==1`

Comment: 'np.sum(Alpha)' return 'Variable((7,))' it is not linked to the value of the coefficients in  Alpha

Concerning the comment about  putting 'A @ Alpha - B =0' as a constraint, for me it's the minimization problem, I just want to be "close" to 0 not to achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just `sum(Alpha) == 1`. You are not supposed to use `numpy` functions in CVXPY expressions, you must use CVXPY functions listed in https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html